# How to pass a modified data object list to the controller?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm new, so there are some things that are not very clear to me, but I have a list in which I show in the html with data that works fine, but if I try to modify a field and try to save, once it reaches the controller I see that just the GridLanguageList is null, so I cannot save those changes that have been made to the view.

In the html I show the data in this way:

```
@if (Model.GridLanguageList != null && Model.GridLanguageList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = Model.GridLanguageList.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    //var currentItem = Model.GridLanguageList[i];
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].IdCaseLanguage)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].IdCase)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].IdLanguageIso)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].FormatType)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].PublicationDate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].RevisionDate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].ModPdfDate)
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panelIese">
                            <div class="panel-heading bg-danger  text-white">
                                <div class="col-md-11">
                                    @Model.GridLanguageList[i].DescripLanguageIso
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="panelSpanish" class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.Raw("Title test:")
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].Title, 3, 300, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", maxlength = "250" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubTitle)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].SubTitle, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", maxlength = "360" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PublicationDate_, new { style = "display: block;" })
                                        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("PublicationDate_"+ i + "").Format(Constants.DateFormat).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dateForm" }).Value(Model.GridLanguageList[i].PublicationDate))
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RevisionDate_, new { style = "display: block;" })
                                        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("RevisionDate_" + i + "").Format(Constants.DateFormat).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dateForm" }).Value(Model.GridLanguageList[i].RevisionDate))
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pages)
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].Pages, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "5" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].FormatType)
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].FormatType, Model.FormatTypesList, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
```

And in the controller at the moment this is what I do:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> Detail(MaterialDetailViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Logger.Info(string.Format(Messages.Logger_StartSaveModel, Literals.Materials_Detail, viewModel.IdMaterial.ToString(), ControllerKeys.Material), User.Identity.Name, Session.SessionID);

                if (viewModel.OperationDone == Actions.Save || viewModel.OperationDone == Actions.SaveFile || viewModel.OperationDone == Actions.InitialChange || viewModel.OperationDone == Actions.NewLanguageIso)
                {

                    if (viewModel.OperationDone == Actions.InitialChange)
                    {
                        viewModel = viewModel.ChangeInitial();
                    }

                    var selectedLanguageIsoId = viewModel.NewLanguageIso;

                    if (viewModel.OperationDone == Actions.NewLanguageIso )
                    {
                        var newCaseLanguage = new CaseLanguage(viewModel.IdMaterial, selectedLanguageIsoId, User.Identity.Name);
                        viewModel.GridLanguageList = _apiCases.SaveCaseLanguage(newCaseLanguage).ToViewModel();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have edited the question with the new changes I have made, I see that some fields are modified and sent to the controller, but I have found that not all of them are and I don't know why. Specifically, all the fields that are TextAreaFor or TextBoxFor are informed and if they are modified, they reach the controller correctly.

But I have come across cases like

> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].FormatType, Model.FormatTypesList, new { @class= "form-control form-control-sm" })

that comes informed with a value for the list selector in this case with a 1 that should show "Text", but it always shows me in the selector "Video" which It is value 2 and even if I modify it and send it to the controller I always see that it arrives at 1, that is, it does not give me the value of another element that I have supposedly modified.

And another cases like:

> @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("RevisionDate_" + i +
> "").Format(Constants.DateFormat).HtmlAttributes(new { @class =
> "dateForm" }).Value(Model.GridLanguageList[i].RevisionDate))

with the dates, they can arrive empty or informed from BDD, in these cases that I propose they arrive null, but if I try to select a date with the datepicker and send it to the controller to do the update, these fields always arrive null or if there is a value informed although I changed it with the datepicker, it is still the same as it arrived.

I have checked that all the fields are called the same, have the same data type, I have debugged, I have set the fields as hidden to see if that would change, but I honestly don't know why some fields do it well and others do nothing. I'm going a little crazy

Any advice or help is very useful to me, but I'm a little stuck.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the currentItem and work directly with GridL object

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].Title, 3, 300, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", maxlength = "250" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].SubTitle, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", maxlength = "360" })
```

kendo datePicker

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("GridLanguageList[" + i + "].PublicationDate").Format(Constants.DateFormat).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dateForm" }).Value(Model.GridLanguageList[i].PublicationDate))
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("GridLanguageList[" + i + "].RevisionDate").Format(Constants.DateFormat).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dateForm" }).Value(Model.GridLanguageList[i].RevisionDate))
```

Comment: I have done what you told me and it works!!, but there are fields like the id that, for example, arrive null. Would your thing be to add @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].Id) ?

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GridLanguageList[i].Id)

Comment: For the kendo datepicker and dropdownlistfor fields it does not work, for the datepicker it does not modify the date and when sending to the controller it arrives unchanged and in the case of the dropdownlist it does not select the appropriate value and even if it is modified it is not sent